# Novice Programmer In need of help for a school Project

Tags: java

Stock Market Project. Finding errors where the double asterisk's start and end. Tried to fix on my own but to of no avail. 
I really don't have that much knowledge of programming so i might be missing some key symbols, but I just don't know where they would have to go.

```
package Price;

    import java.util.Scanner;


    **public class Trade {**

        public void StockMarket () {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            double next = 0,
                    sum = 0;
        } 
            public double openpricedow;
            public double closepricedow;
            public double currentpricedow;
            public double lowpricedow;

            public double openpricenas;
            public double closepricenas;
            public double currentpricenas;
           public double lowpricenas;

            public double openpricesp;
            public double closepricesp;
            public double currentpricesp;
            public double lowpricesp;

            String company, dow, nas, sp;
            int NumberofShares = 0;


            public void Trade()
            {


            System.out.println("Welcome to the Stock Market");
            System.out.println("Please enter your stock company");




            }
            **public double findPrice();**



             **findPrice();
            company = keyboard.next();**


            **Switch (company){**
                **case "dow":**
                    System.out.println("Please enter your number of shares");
                    //Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);//

                    openpricedow = 11.50;
                    closepricedow = 18;
                    lowpricedow = 14.50;
                    currentpricedow = 12.50;

                    boolean areMore = true;
                    while (areMore = true) {

                        next = keyboard.nextInt();


                        if (next < 0) {
                            areMore = false;
                        } else {
                            sum = Numberofshares + next;
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(" You have bought " + sum + " shares at  $ " + currentpricedow + " and your total is  $ " + (sum * currentpricedow));




                    // if (Shares > 1000) {
                    //  double returnedShares = (Shares * currentpricedow);
                    // System.out.println("You have bought " + Shares + " shares at  $" + currentpricesp + " and your total is  $" + returnedShares);

                    if (Shares < 1000) {
                        System.out.println("Your number of shares are insufficient");
                    }


                case "sp":
                    System.out.println("Please enter your number of shares");
                    //Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);//
                    //Shares = keyboard.nextInt();
                    openpricesp = 13.50;
                    closepricesp = 16;
                    lowpricesp = 15.50;
                    currentpricesp = 8;

                    Shares = 0;
                    next = keyboard.nextDouble();

                    while (next > 0) {
                        sum = +sum + next;
                        Shares++;
                        next = keyboard.nextDouble();
                    }
                    if (next < 0) {
                        System.out.println(" You have bought " + sum + " shares at  $ " + currentpricesp + " and your total is  $ " + (sum * currentpricesp));

                    } // if (Shares > 1000) {
                    //  double returnedShares = (Shares * currentpricesp);
                    // System.out.println("You have bought " + Shares + " shares at  $" + currentpricesp + " and your total is  $" + returnedShares);
                    else if (Shares < 1000) {
                        System.out.println("Your number of shares are insufficient");
                    }

                case "nas":
                    System.out.println("Please enter your number of shares");
                    //Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);//
                    Shares = keyboard.nextInt();
                    openpricenas = 12.50;
                    closepricenas = 14;
                    lowpricenas = 17.50;
                    currentpricenas = 9.80;
                    if (closepricenas < lowpricenas) {
                        System.out.println("Your cannot buy shares at this moment");
                    } else {
                        Shares = 0;
                        next = keyboard.nextDouble();
                        while (next > 0) {
                            sum = sum + next;
                            Shares++;
                            next = keyboard.nextDouble();
                        }
                        if (next < 0) {
                            System.out.println(" You have bought " + sum + " shares at  $ " + currentpricenas + " and your total is  $ " + (sum * currentpricenas));

    }
    }

    }


    // if (Shares > 1000) {
                        //   double returnedShares = (Shares * currentpricenas);
                        // System.out.println("You have bought " + Shares + " shares at  $" + currentpricenas + " and your total is  $" + returnedShares);}

    **else if (Shares < 1000)
                            System.out.println("Your number of shares are insufficient");

        return findPrice;}**
    **}**

        enter code here







    public class Price {
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {Trade dow = new Trade();  //<=====buy is the object. stock is the class.
    dow.openpricedow  = 11.50;
    dow.closepricedow  = 18;
    dow.currentpricedow = 14.50;
    dow.lowpricedow = 12.50;

    dow.Trade();
    double result = dow.findPrice();
    System.out.println("The higher Stock is " + result);
    }
    {Trade nas = new Trade();  //<=====buy is the object. stock is the class.
    nas.openpricenas = 11.50;
    nas.closepricenas  = 18;
    nas.currentpricenas = 14.50;
    nas.lowpricenas = 12.50;

    nas.Trade();
    double result = nas.findPrice();
    System.out.println("The higher Stock is " + result);
    }
    {Trade sp = new Trade();  //<=====buy is the object. stock is the class.
    sp.openpricesp = 13.50;
    sp.closepricesp  = 16;
    sp.currentpricesp = 15.50;
    sp.lowpricesp = 8;

    sp.Trade();
    double result = sp.findPrice();
    System.out.println("The higher Stock is " + result);

                        // }


            }

    }
```

Comment: ***Relevant*** code only, please. And fix the formatting while you're revamping it.

Comment: What errors do you get?  Style and readability matter.  Follow the Sun Java coding standards and pay attention to brace placement, et.

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: Don't waste other's people time putting symbols in source code that they have to remove, the compiler is much better than you in signaling errors..

Comment: I didnt put the symbols there. I tried to make the lines bold and that's what came up.....

Answer (score 0):

Declare this as global.

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
```

There is incorrect syntax: 
 `public double findPrice();`

Change this to:

```
public double findPrice(){
  // your remain code..
}
```

In `switch` case you must add `break`. if not remain case will be execute.. like this..

```
switch(opt){
   case "a":
       // your remain code..
       break;
  case "b":
       // your remain code..
       break;
}
```